# Use Pixels to set positions and size in Android?

Tags: java, android

I know people asked how to support different sizes but they only cared about the dimensions of the images. My question is somehow different. I want to know if using pixels is a good way to scale everything and also to position images on the screen.
Is there a better way?
I am creating a 2D game BTW.

Regards,
Baracat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way that you can do is to having many sets of images at many resolutions as possible then load it dynamically depends on the screen resolution. I am using this method for menus in my 2D games.

EDIT:
For positioning please have a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7452412/android-screen-size-algorithm-pattern/7452474#7452474)

Comment: But I am asking about setting positions also

Comment: Setting position please have a look at my post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7452412/android-screen-size-algorithm-pattern/7452474#7452474

Comment: Ok so calculating the screen position based on a percentage of the screen width right?
Another thing, Is adding forexample the image as 32x32 for small screen then 35x35 for larger screen means that when the game is running on the larger screen it will load the 35x35?
So it is a way to evade blurry images?

Comment: It will definitely blur if you scale it up. Note that it will slow your game down in order to scale your image(s). The best way i can think is preparing different sizes of an image to cope with different resolution.

Comment: last thing, Could you tell me why do we care about the density I cant seem to understand

Comment: Because users want to see something beautiful :) I personally don't care about density as long as i can recognize images in my game.

Comment: Yea I know what you mean but I meant another thing. I read that when scaling do not use real pixels. Is the only reason for this that the images will look blurry? If yes, so why the screens are categorized for Android into density categories. Now I could find 2 480x800 screens one with high density and other with low. So When I supply 2 different images One will have for example 34 and the otehr 35 BUT Shouldnt both have the same texture or this would make the layout different?

Comment: please start the new question. This is becoming a chat.