# How to make Standard game design/layout through Surfaceview

Tags: java, android, canvas, surfaceview

I have used SurfaceView in my game. Right Now, I have created layout considering one device (320 x 480). The game layout looks nice and all functions are working properly. But when I see the same game in another device with different dimension (screen size), the layout does not seem to be proper.

So is there any property, method, formula or helping Tutorial by which I can create game design/layout through canvas which looks same in all screen size devices.

Comment: Take a look here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7452412/android-screen-size-algorithm-pattern/7452474#7452474

Answer (score 1):

There is one simple hint: don't ever use absolute coordinates on the `SurfaceView`. Every item's position should be calculated at runtime depending on the actual screen size. This way you'll achieve a layout that will look the same way on every device. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.

Is there any specific formula or method that can be used. 
Calculating position for each object may be somewhat tricky in my case.

Or is there any game sample code available which can help!

Again thanks for the help!!

Comment: @Devon Smith, No specific formulas or something, just the idea. For example, you need to position your object on 20 pixels on X axis on a HVGA phone. Calculate coeff = HVGA phone width / 20, and then use (actual width / coeff) instead of 20. I hope the idea is clear, anyway, if you have any more questions, feel free to ask.